# how can i send post data from javascript to php?

Tags: php, javascript, post

How can I send post data from javascript to php?

I have this script for pinning a point in google maps, but the data sent from post doesn't show in test.php. What am i doing wrong? I need to get the longitude and latitude from the js file to the db. Thanks.

**pin.php**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqPinMyLocation.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').jqPinMyLocation({
            serverUrl   : 'test.php',//Server url 
            requestType : 'POST', // Type of request that we will send to server
            additionalData : {//Additional data that will be send to server after user drag the cursor
                userid: 2
            },
            address : 'Bucharest, Romania'//You need to provide the default address where the map will be centered
        });
    });
</script>
```

**js file**

```
var sendNewPositionToServer = function(LatLng) {
    var coordinates = {
        latitude    : LatLng.lat(),
        longitude   : LatLng.lng()
    };
    if( settings.serverUrl !== undefined ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : settings.serverUrl,

            type : (settings.requesttype !== undefined)?settings.requesttype  : 'post',
            data :$.extend(coordinates, settings.additionalData),
            success : function() {

            }
        });
    }
};
```

and last the php file where I have to send the post data.

```
echo $_POST['userid'];
echo $_POST['longitude'];
```

Comment: you can use ajax for this. hav u tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use JQuery For This but
I Use

> formdata()

(is a js function) for make a post data after that post it With ajax